# <v-time-picker> - time picker not working

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, timepicker

`<v-time-picker>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="">Time</label>

    <v-time-picker
         class="theme-orange"
         v-model="time"
         input-class="form-control"
         type="time"
         auto>
    </v-time-picker>

</div>
```

I need to get only time picker, how can i fix this issue?

Comment: you need to add VTimePicker , see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte

Answer (score 0):

This is the Vuetify code for the time picker

```
<v-time-picker v-model="time" header-color="primary"></v-time-picker>
```

You must make sure that you have the v-model associated even in the JS, the variable in your JS can be null or string and you can use it for any function.

In your JS it must be like this

```
data:{
   time: ''(this is most recommended) or time: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have not imported the component in your file. Another approach is to add `vuetify` globally to your project. To fix this, add the following line in your `main.js/index.js` file:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
// ...other import statements

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```